# angular 2 http get request not fetching data via node server while http post works fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I am trying to fetch data from Mongo DB using angular2 and node server 
    via http get request. When I am trying to view the get response in 
    browser ,I can see html tags as value of "_body" but if same http get 
    request is changed to http post then reponse is as below :

```
"{"success":true,"sellerdata":[]}" as value of "_body".
```

Why post is working with same code configuration but not get request?

Here is my angular Code. All required imports are present in class.
This is service class where get observable created.

```
/**(post changes which is working fine)return 
this.http.post('/sellerlist',{}).map(**/

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  getSellerdata(){
    return this.http.get('/sellerlist').map( 
      (res:Response ) =>{return res.json();})      
  }}
```

This is subscriber class where request is initiated and response is logged on browser console.

```
@Component({selector: 'app-admin-sellers',})
export class AdminSellersComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private adminService :AdminService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.adminService.getSellerdata().subscribe(
      (dataFromServer) => {console.log(dataFromServer);});  // 
  }}
```

Here is my node server JS. All server side configurations are present here.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('localhost/testapp')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
app.use('/secure/*', secureRoutes);
function secureRoutes(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.headers['token'];
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function (err, decode) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send('Email & Password do not match');
      } else {
        next();
      }});
  } else {console.log(2)}};
app.all("/secure/*", secureRoutes, function (req, res, next) {
  next();});
app.get('/sellerlist', getSellerList);
/**(post changes which is working fine)
app.post('/sellerlist', getSellerList);**/
```

Comment: Probably because the server doesn't respond with data when a POST request is sent.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. Are you saying 1. Expected data is not returned in response 2. Don't know what to do with data from response. All I see is a `.subscribe()` with a `console.log()` inside and no attempt to actually assign that value anywhere. If **1** is the problem, then your question lacks the relevant code or testing of the function actually working with the database itself. And of course it's only a GET method. No POST here.

Comment: there is no method `app.post('/sellerlist')` in your node js

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I am trying to view the expected data using console.log , once I will see the data then I will assign it to relevant code.My problem is if I replace this.http.get('/sellerlist') with this.http.post('/sellerlist',{}) in service class and app.get('/sellerlist', getSellerList); with app.post('/sellerlist', getSellerList); , it print data correctly in browser console.Hopefully now my question is clear

Comment: @ParthGhiya As post is working , I have not mentioned above but I want to understand why get is not working with node server. FYI.if I replace this.http.get('/sellerlist') with this.http.post('/sellerlist',{}) in service class and app.get('/sellerlist', getSellerList); with app.post('/sellerlist', getSellerList); , it print data correctly in browser console

Comment: what does your `getSellerList ` do ? post its code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Post is working fine.Get is having issue.I have updated my question. Hope , it's clear now

Comment: @ParthGhiya var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var sellers = require('../models/sellerModel');


var getSellerList= function getSellerList(req, res) {
 console.log('seller');
    sellers.find({}, (err, seller) => {
     console.log(seller);
            res.json({
                success: true,
                sellerdata: seller
            });
    });
}
module.exports = getSellerList;

Comment: @ParthGhiya I have added code in comment for getSellerList. This is used to get data from mongo DB

Answer (score 1):

```
Problem was present in server side configuration.

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
}); 

is written before

app.get('/sellerlist', getSellerList);

So all get requests are handled by the default configuration . After reversing the above order , get requests worked.
```